# JS not working when making a Wordpress theme from an HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Here is my issue: I have an HTML template that has CSS, JS and some IMAGES attached to it. I converted it to a wordpress theme by following the very basic and simple instructions here: http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/ . In order for the images to show, I have to upload them to the WP library and then change the links in the index.php and other files so they point not to /img/picture.jpg, but to www.sitename.com/wp-uploads/2012/11/picture.jpg.

When I do that, the pictures show just fine. However, I then try to upload the JS files to the library as well. That goes OK. Then I go and replace the links to them in the header.php file with the links that now point to the site. Just like above. However, the JS isn't responsing at all.

Can you give me any tips on what I migth be doing wrong? I already went through all the files to see if I haven't missed a link, but everything seems fine.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Any live example? Did you check the paths? Are the js files loaded?

Comment: This is how they are added in the header.php file: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1xx.24.36.xx7//wp-content/uploads/2012/11/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1xx.24.36.xx7//wp-content/uploads/2012/11/jquery.sexyslider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1xx.24.36.1xx//wp-content/uploads/2012/11/moving-clouds.js"></script>

Can you please tell me what it means for the js files to be loaded? Yes, the paths are all checked and doublechecked

Comment: Take a look at doublesharp's answer. It contains the proper methods to include the files and construct your theme. By _script loaded_, I meant to ask whether the http request for the js files was indeed recognized by your server and returned the script content with response code 200 (ok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript and CSS files should not go in the Media Uploader, they should be included in your theme. From there, you can enqueue them to be included in your header using `wp_enqueue_script` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script - and `wp_enqueue_style` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style.

The proper way to determine the page is to use the `get_template_directory_uri()` function.

For example if you want to register `/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/js/script.js` and it relies on `jQuery` you would use this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
wp_enqueue_script('script_name', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/script.js" ,'jquery',false,true);
```

Comment: Here is how I wrote the code: 

<?php wp_enqueue_script('1.7.1.min', WP_CONTENT_URL . 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/cloudit/wp-content/themes/custom2/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'); ?>

However its still not registering. Would you please take a look?

Comment: Yes I read the wp_enqueue_script post. I also uploaded the files alongside the theme, and I can access them from the link I've posted above, so I have the path right. Now the thing that is left is the correct code it seems. I can't quite find an example thats working. So far tried wp_enqueue_script('name' 'path') and wp_enqueue_script('path') . No change so far.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! TO be completely speciffic: In my header.php I have this line: 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moving-clouds.js">     </script>`
And I tried replacing it, after having uploaded the files along with the theme with this:

    `<?php wp_enqueue_script('moving-clouds.js',     get_template_directory_uri()."/js/moving-clouds.js"      ,'jquery',false,true);?>`

I don't have a functions.php file in this theme. It still doesn't register the JS. I also tried the full path, not just the `/js/filename.js `

Any other ideas?

Comment: just create a file called `functions.php` and add that it to. you will also need to make sure you have `<?php wp_head() ?>` somewhere in your header. it won't work if you put it straight into the header.

Comment: Hey, doublesharp, so I did both. I pasted everything in a functions.php and I put a `<?php wp_head() ?>` in the header.php. Still no go. None of the JS scripts seem to function. The synthax in the functions php is as follows: `
<?php wp_enqueue_script('moving-clouds.js', get_template_directory_uri()."http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/cloudit/wp-content/themes/stonecustom2/js/moving-clouds.js" ,'jquery',false,true);?> `

Comment: Remove "xxx.xx.xx.xxx/cloudit/wp-content/themes/stonecustom2" - that is what the `get_template_directory_uri()` will add automatically.

Comment: OK I just did that. I also found out that I had written the wp_head twice. With both those fixed, still the js hasn't activated. The functions.php file is filled with only these wp_enqueue_script and nothing else. There aren't any wp_enqueue_script in the header file.

Comment: the function will automatically add it to wp_head - does it require jquery? in the example i sent, it will wait to add your script until jquery is loaded, so if you don't, it wont show up. if you don't need jquery, just remove the `'jquery'` part and replace with null or and empty string.

Comment: Dear everyone, and especially doublesharp who was so very kind to help me: I could not find my way around with the get_template_directory_uri() function. It just wasn't happening, so instead I decided to host the JS/CSS files over at google by following this tutorial http://www.intechgrity.com/freely-host-css-js-other-static-files/# Everything works perfectly. Thank you very much for your kind support and have a great day!